# How do you test BiometricPrompt API's face auth without a physical Pixel 4 device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-biometric-prompt

How does one set up an emulator like Pixel 4 with face unlock capabilities to test/dev for face unlock? I don't see it as an option in android studio's emulator hardware profiles.

If I understand correctly, it's supposed to "just work" if using the BiometricPrompt API already for fingerprints, but I would like to test face unlock on an emulator too at least.